# SQL Substring Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column named full name. I want to split them into two columns, first name and last name.

I am having a trouble with a persons with two first names. If the first name encounters a space it was considered last name.

I want this:

```
Full name : John Michael Smith
Firstname: John Michael
Lastname: Smith
```

However, I am getting:

```
Firstname: John
Lastname: Michael Smith
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Full name : John Michael Smith
Firstname: John Michael
Lastname: Smith

I am getting

Firstname: John
Lastname: Michael Smith

Comment: reverse the string, get the position of the first space, substring from 1 to that position

Comment: how? please help.

Comment: @simpleCode, Google is your friend

Comment: Share your full code here.

Comment: @simpleCode . . . That information belongs in the question, not a comment. Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
declare @n varchar(max) = 'John Michael Smith'

select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@n),  CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@n)), 100)) FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link:

[SQL SERVER – Reverse String Word By Word – Part 2](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/12/15/sql-server-reverse-string-word-by-word-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by checking for the index of last space and using it with `LEFT` and `RIGHT` function.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100)= 'John Michael Smith'
SELECT LEFT(@name,LEN(@name)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@name))) AS [Firstname],RIGHT(@name,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@name))) AS [LastName]
```

Answer (score 0):

**--Create table from below script**

```
create table users(id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(50));
```

**--Insert Record for query for testing**

```
insert into users(name)
values('John Abraham'),
('John Mark Abraham'),
('John Vens Abraham'),
('John Abraham');
```

**--Run below query for getting all inserted records.**

```
select * from users;
```

**--Run below query for getting first and last name from name**

```
 select id , name, SUBSTRING(name,0, CHARINDEX(last_name,name)) as first_name, last_name from
    (
    select id, name,  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(name),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(name)))) as last_name from users
    ) as A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hi-jack 'parsename'. This only works up to 4 intervals but a nice option;

```
declare @name varchar(100)

set @name='John Michael Smith'

select PARSENAME(REPLACE(@name,' ','.'),1) -- returns Smith
select PARSENAME(REPLACE(@name,' ','.'),2) -- returns Micheal
select PARSENAME(REPLACE(@name,' ','.'),3) -- Returns John
select PARSENAME(REPLACE(@name,' ','.'),4) -- returns NULL
```